# Particle moving along an $x$ - axis - Ranking its accelerations

Tags: kinematics

The figure below shows that a particle moving along an $x$ - axis undergoes three periods of acceleration. Without written computation, rank the acceleration periods according to the increases they produce in the particle’s velocity, greatest first.
[image]

I'm not sure if I'm correct with my answer, but would it go 1 and 2 tie, and then 3?

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer? If yes, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct. The simple calculation behind it is that increase in velocity is given by $a\cdot t$, which corresponds to the area of each rectangle. By simply counting the squares inside each rectangle you obtain the solution you gave.